# web page http post check tools

Tags: http, post, get

im tasked to secure a web project. and the codes are messy. basically i need to focus on webpages that are using http GET and do proper validation or convert to http POST.

is there a free tool out there that runs on linux which search and generate a report?

Answer (score 0):

A report of what http get requets are made by a web application?

Well, what about a simple network sniffer, like `tcpdump` or `wireshark`? lists you every request made. And you can process the dump using plain cli processing tools like grep and sed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool in my knowledge which will generate a report like that.What you can do this , intercept the get & post requests using the tool called [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) ( windows only ) , It will list all the request & response which goes IN & OUT of a browser.

1. Install fiddler, start it.
2. Access the application
3. Go through the application and check the Fiddler interface.
4. It will list all the GET & POST data
5. You can generate report by examining this data.